# How to return groupby values from a Pandas dataFrame?

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas

I have a dataFrame I have summarized some data in and I am graphing it. I want to get the values from the groupby field to use as the labels in the graph.

Here is my summarized dataFrame:

```
code_values = code_graph.groupby(['code_desc']).agg({'product_id': pd.Series.nunique })
```

Which returns:

```
print code_values
                          product_id
code_desc                          
Product 1                         30
Product 2                         40
Product 3                         50
Product 4                         60
```

When I try to access the code_desc field to use in a matplotlib graph as the labels I get:

```
print code_values['code_desc']
KeyError: u'no item named code_desc'
```

How can I get the values for code_desc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the aggregated values, you should be able to use:

```
code_values.index
```

You can also get the keys of the groups dictionary of the groupby object, like:

```
grouped = code_graph.groupby(['code_desc'])
code_desc = grouped.groups.keys()
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to access them as values, they probably shouldn't be your index anymore. Consider in the end

```
code_values.reset_index(inplace=True)
print code_values['code_desc']
```

However, a lot of built-in [visualization tools of pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html) will actually plot values against your index. So, perhaps you want to keep the index but have a look at these?

Answer (score 0):

use index for single level index.  if you have a multi level index you can get the index value by index level.

```
 txt="""code_desc,product_id
 Product 1,                         30
 Product 1,                         70
 Product 2,                         40
 Product 3,                         50
 Product 4,                         60"""

 from io import StringIO
 f = StringIO(txt)
 df = pd.read_table(f,sep =',')

 grouped = df.groupby(['code_desc']).agg({'product_id': pd.Series.nunique })
 labels=grouped.index
 print(labels)
```

output:

```
 Index(['Product 1', 'Product 2', 'Product 3', 'Product 4'], dtype='object', name='code_desc')
```